# regex subtitution

Tags: python, regex

tried:

```py
typosRegex = re.compile(r'(\w* ){2,}')

mo2 = typosRegex.sub(r'\1', 'ram is a good good personalities.')

print(mo2)
```

result:

```
good personalities.
```

expect:

```
ram is a good personalities.
```

how to get the expected substituted string using regex?
how to replace accidently repeated word with the single of that?

Comment: `(\w* ){2,}` does not mean "the same word twice in a row". It means "two in a row of *any word*". So "ram is" and "a good" get substituted out. "good personalities." does not, only because there is no trailing space.

Comment: `re.sub(r'(\w+)\s+\1',r'\1', your_string)`